# Application can't start android?

Tags: android, eclipse, exception, launch

I've made an application but at the time I want to test it, it gives the message `the application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again`. It seems that it has an error in line 68, but I can't find it. What is wrong?

Heres the code:

```
package com.example.kapscht;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
CheckBox checkgrua; 
CheckBox checkreader1; 
CheckBox checkreader2;
CheckBox checkctm1;
CheckBox checkctm2; 
CheckBox checkpsm1; 
CheckBox checkpsm2;
CheckBox checklbm1;
CheckBox checklbm2;
CheckBox checkrx1;
CheckBox checkrx2; 
CheckBox checktx1; 
CheckBox checktx2;
CheckBox checkmodulerf1;
CheckBox checkmodulerf2; 
CheckBox checkmodulemrf1;
CheckBox checkmodulemrf2;
CheckBox checkcablerf1; 
CheckBox checkcablerf2;
CheckBox checkconectorrf1;
CheckBox checkconectorrf2;
CheckBox checkatenuacionrf1;
CheckBox checkatenuacionrf2; 
CheckBox checkloopback1; 
CheckBox checkloopback2;
CheckBox checkfirmware1;
CheckBox checkfirmware2; 
CheckBox checkethernet1; 
CheckBox checkethernet2;
CheckBox checkamplificador1;
CheckBox checkamplificador2;
CheckBox checkfp1;
CheckBox checkfp2; 
CheckBox checksincro1; 
CheckBox checksincro2;
CheckBox checkotro1;
CheckBox checkotro2; 
EditText etsitio; 
EditText etfalla;
EditText etdescripcion;
EditText etqg;
TextView vwfecha1; 
TextView vwfecha2; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Date date = new Date(0);
    String dateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);
    vwfecha1.setText(dateTime);
    checkgrua= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkgrua);
    checkreader1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkreader1);
    checkreader2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkreader2);
    checkctm1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkctm1);
    checkctm2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkctm2);
    checkpsm1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkpsm1);
    checkpsm2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkpsm2);
    checklbm1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checklbm1);
    checklbm2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checklbm2);
    checkrx1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkrx1);
    checkrx2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkrx2);
    checktx1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checktx1);
    checktx2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checktx2);
    checkmodulerf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulerf1);
    checkmodulerf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulerf2);
    checkmodulemrf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulemrf1);
    checkmodulemrf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkmodulemrf2);
    checkcablerf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkcablerf1);
    checkcablerf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkcablerf2);
    checkconectorrf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkconectorrf1);
    checkconectorrf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkconectorrf2);
    checkatenuacionrf1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkatenuacionrf1);
    checkatenuacionrf2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkatenuacionrf2);
    checkloopback1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkloopback1);
    checkloopback2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkloopback2);
    checkfirmware1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfirmware1);
    checkfirmware2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfirmware2);
    checkethernet1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkethernet1);
    checkethernet2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkethernet2);
    checkamplificador1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkamplificador1);
    checkamplificador2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkamplificador2);
    checkfp1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfp1);
    checkfp2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkfp2);
    checksincro1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checksincro1);
    checksincro2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checksincro2);
    checkotro1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkotro1);
    checkotro2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkotro2);
    etsitio= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsitio);
    etfalla= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etfalla); 
    etdescripcion= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etdescripcion);
    etqg= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etqg);
    View boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enviar);
    boton.setOnClickListener(this); 

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==findViewById(R.id.enviar).getId())
    {
        Intent intentEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "villasantdesign@gmail.com", null));
        intentEmail.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"villasantdesign@gmail.com"});
        intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Consulta Técnica");
        intentEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Fecha/hora abierto: "+vwfecha1.getText().toString()+"\nSitio:  "+etsitio.getText()+"\nSe usó grua:  "+checkgrua.isChecked()+"\nFalla Reportada:  "+etfalla.getText()+"\nSe reemplazó reader/lector: "+checkreader1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó reader/lector: "+checkreader2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó CTM:  "+checkctm1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó CTM:  "+checkctm2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó PSM: "+checkpsm1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó PSM: "+checkpsm2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó LBM:  "+checklbm1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó LBM:  "+checklbm2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Antena Rx: "+checkrx1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Antena Rx: "+checkrx2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Antena Tx:  "+checktx1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Antena Tx:  "+checktx2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Módulo RF: "+checkmodulerf1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Módulo RF: "+checkmodulerf2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Módulo MRF:  "+checkmodulemrf1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Módulo MRF:  "+checkmodulemrf2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Cable/Jumper RF: "+checkcablerf1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Cable/Jumper RF: "+checkcablerf2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Conector RF:  "+checkconectorrf1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Conector RF:  "+checkconectorrf2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Atenuación RF: "+checkatenuacionrf1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Atenuación RF: "+checkatenuacionrf2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Cable Loopback RF: "+checkloopback1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Cable Loopback RF: "+checkloopback2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó SW/Firmware: "+checkfirmware1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó SW/Firmware: "+checkfirmware2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Conexión Ethernet:  "+checkethernet1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Conexión Ethernet:  "+checkethernet2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Amplificador: "+checkamplificador1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Amplificador: "+checkamplificador2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó FP Amp.:  "+checkfp1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó FP Amp.:  "+checkfp2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó Sincronización: "+checksincro1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó Sincronización: "+checksincro2.isChecked()+"\nSe reemplazó OTRO:  "+checkotro1.isChecked()+"\nSe ajustó OTRO:  "+checkotro2.isChecked());         
        intentEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentEmail, "Enviar"));         
        }}}
```

And here is the error log Logcat jeeps giving me when I try to launch my application:

```
07-29 12:37:35.269: W/dalvikvm(10939): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e560)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kapscht/com.example.kapscht.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1702)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1727)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:124)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:974)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3859)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:890)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:648)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at com.example.kapscht.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)   
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1666)
07-29 12:37:35.289: E/AndroidRuntime(10939):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to call a method (`setText())`, on `vwfecha1` but you haven't initialized it yet so it is `null`. Change your `onCreate()`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Date date = new Date(0);
String dateTime = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(date);

vwfecha1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idOfvwfecha1);  // add this line with the appropriate id
vwfecha1.setText(dateTime);
```

Also, I'm not sure what this line in your `onClick()` will give

```
v.getId()==findViewById(R.id.enviar).getId()
```

but it can simply be

```
v.getId()==R.id.enviar
```

It looks like it will do the same thing but you are taking extra, unnecessary steps

Comment: @323go thanks for the edit but the "()" were there on purpose. I like to keep things like that together...I do the same thing when I compare the `id`s in a `switch`

Comment: You know how I can generate an exit time and date? The first variable was to generate a time of entering the application, I want another date to generate the time im getting out of the app.

Comment: That just depends on your definition of "exit" I guess and how you handle your app lifecycle. If they press the "Home" key does that count? If so, you will need a listener in each `Activity` for the home key press. If just when they back out then never finish your first `Activity` until they press the back button on it and get the time there.

Comment: No, It would be at the time they press the "Enviar" button, that would count as the exit of the application. The thing is that we want to record diagnosis time so its kind of important.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Get the `currentTimeInMillis()` when they press that `Button`.